# How do I free up space (delete things) taken up by my iPad's Photo Library?

Tags: ipad, photos, storage, camera

I have an older iPad that I got in 2012. The iOS version is 8.1

A lot of space is used by my "Photos & Camera".  I clicked on my "Camera" icon and after clicking on its gallery, I clicked the "Trash" icon next to every item in there.  However, when I go into my Storage Settings, and drill down to my "Photos & Camera", it says "8.9 GB," but there's no where that allows me to delete the items used by the storage.

How do I actually delete things?  That is, I'm trying to free up storage, which I can't seem to do.

Answer (score 1):

On the newer iOS versions, Apple initiated a delayed trash. This means that things are only truly deleted after they've been in the trash for 30 days.

To force things to delete, go to the photos app, then choose albums in the bottom right corner. Scroll down until you find the "recently deleted" album and click on it. Then click select and choose whether you want to delete or recover either all or just a few of the photos.

Comment: I'm not able to update to the newer iOS because i don't have enough storage.  Also, I don't have a "Photos" app.  I have a "Camera" app and a "Photo Booth" app.  Are you thinking of one of those?

Comment: @Dave What iOS are you running? (Settings -> general -> about)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It is version 8.1.

Comment: @Dave you do have a photos app. Look at the picture in the link - it's the flowery app icon in the top row second from the right. https://cdn.ampproject.org/ii/w820/s/i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--uLw8BmMU--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/yrlpbwckqm8g5wwyij9u.jpg

Comment: Thanks.  I found what you're talking about.  When I click the "Delete Photo" on the selected photo, the app exits and when I click back into the app, the photos are still there.  Am I supposed to be kicked out of the app when I click "Delete Photo"?

Answer (score -1):

Go through general>usage then you should see where to delete the photos.  If not you can always go to the photos app then delete the photos there.